# user registration error: Token is required

Tags: android, quickblox

I want to create registration in chat.

In application.java onCreate I use:

```
        QBSettings.getInstance().fastConfigInit(APP_ID, AUTH_KEY, AUTH_SECRET);
    StickersManager.initialize(STICKER_API_KEY, this);
    ChatService.initIfNeed(this);
```

In my activity I use:

```
            ChatService.initIfNeed(EditProfileActivity.this);

            final QBUser chatUser = new QBUser("userlogin", "userpass");
            QBUsers.signUp(chatUser, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBUser>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QBUser user, Bundle args) {
                    // success
                    Log.e("chat", "registered");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(List<String> errors) {
                    // error
                    Log.e("chat", "registration error");
                }
            });
```

but getting next error in OnError: **Token is required**

Which token is it needed? How to register new user from user app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be able to use QuickBlox API you have to create a session.

http://quickblox.com/developers/Android#A_couple_of_words_about_Authentication_and_Authorization

```
QBAuth.createSession(new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBSession>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(QBSession session, Bundle params) {
        // success
        // you can sign up user here
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(List<String> errors) {
        // errors
    }
});
```

Comment: Please try give answer of this , 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715039/multiple-attachment-in-quickblox-android