# Multiple attachment in quickblox android

Tags: java, android, chat, quickblox

I want to upload video with it's thumbnail but unable to attach multiple files together.

In android there is no way to get thumbnail of video from remote url without downloading it. Is there any way in quickblox for getting thumbnail of video ? Or is there anyway I can send thumbnail of video with the video file attachment ? Or can I send multiple attachment in quickblox ?

Please provide details for this . I have searched a lot regarding this but did not find any solution.

If there is any alternate way for getting thumbnail of video please provide the soltution.

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain your domain, like you have access of your videos on server side(i.e you are hosting videos on your own server?) or you are downloading videos from any location?

Comment: I am hosting videos on quickblox server

Comment: If you own your server then there are libraries which can convert into thumbnails on back-end side, but for this scenario I don't think so there would be any method for downloading thumbnails

Comment: If it was my server then there is no problem at all but this is the problem that i am not using my server.

Comment: I think you should generate a ticket to quickblox team, I am sure they will have better solution for this,

Comment: I have already do that but no response from last two days

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90317/discussion-between-akbar-and-kishudroid).

Comment: Why downvote to this question ?  Any reason for that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can send multiple attachment

http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Send_attachment

Call **QBContent.uploadFileTask** as many as you need to upload files

then call **addAttachment**

```
QBAttachment attachment = new QBAttachment("video");
attachment.setId(file.getId().toString());
chatMessage.addAttachment(attachment);
```

so you can add as many attachments as you need

Comment: i have already tried it but i can attach one attachment at time

Comment: What's the exact issue? we need more details about it

Comment: I want to show bitmap of video without downloading it , but in android i can't get thumbnail of video so i want to send video bitmap to quickblox server but am not able to attach multiple attachment together and if it's possible then how we will get public url of bitmap?